# Remember selected option within select menu

Tags: php, html, select

I've googled a lot and found alternative solutions but in my case things are a bit different.

```
<select name='database'>
    <?php foreach($databases as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row; ?>"><?php echo $row; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I need to display the selected option after a POST request in between the option tags but since I already have a value for that I cannot find a way to do so. The idea is that I have one form with a couple of select menus. From the first one I select a database. The second one is for selecting a table from the already chosen database and another select menu for  the columns. The problem is that I'm sending a new request for both the database and table and the chosen database cannot be remembered (it just 'resets' the select menu and starts from the first value).

Here's the [whole code](http://pastebin.com/Gxzbwrn2)

Right now I need to reselect the database which I've previously chosen in order to display the columns from a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name='database'>
    <?php foreach($databases as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?= $row; ?>"
        <?php if ($row == $_POST['database']){echo " selected";}?>> 
            <?= $row; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
 $dbms=$_POST['database'];
<select name='database'>
    <?php foreach($databases as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row; ?>" 
            <?php if ($row == $dbms) echo " selected"; ?> 
        > <?php echo $row; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Uh, no. I find no sense in it whatsoever. Besides it's invalid as syntax and logic as far as I can see.

Comment: `$dbms` should contain the posted value

Comment: $dbms was a variable you used to refer to the current database.